# remove last digits from float value,iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have a float value say 28.980000.
I want something like that 28.98, only 2 values after decimal.
How can i do this ?

Regards

Comment: look at sprintf/[NSString stringWithFormat]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the easiest solutions would be to use `stringWithFormat:` of `NSString`:

```
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%5.2f", floatVal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
-(NSString*)floatToString:(float)val
{

    NSString *result;
    NSArray *numbers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",val], nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",numbers);


    NSArray * floatingPoint = [[numbers objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString * lastObject = [[floatingPoint lastObject] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@""];

        if ([lastObject length] < 2) {
            result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %.2f",[[numbers objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]];
        } else {
            result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %g",[[numbers objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]];
        }

    return result;
}
```